# Why use some_string[-1:] instead of some_string[-1]?

Tags: python, slice

```
foo = 'eggs'

foo[:1] # the same is foo[0]
foo[-1:] # the same is foo[-1]
```

Is there any advantage of one of these ways?

I ran into this over here
https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/xml/etree/ElementPath.py#l254

UPD. Can you go to the link? The variable path is a string there. And I was confused, why they were using a slice instead of a concreate index.

```
if path[-1:] == "/":
```

Comment: this will help you to understand..

[Explain Python's slice notation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: Thank you. I know how it works, but the piece of code above is a reason I was confused.
See the link in my question. Where path is a string.

Comment: The difference is what happens when the string is empty:  extracting a list returns an empty string, while getting a concrete element will raise an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` is a special case, because both slicing and element access will return another `str`.  The difference is what happens when the string is empty: extracting a list returns an empty string, while getting a concrete element will raise an error.

```
--> test = 'hello'
--> test[0]
'h'
--> test[:1]
'h'
--> empty = ''
--> empty[:1]
''
--> empty[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are a special case with slices since an slice return a `str`, but asking for a concrete index also returns a `str`. Unlike C, C++, Java, we don't have a `char` datatype in Python.

You can see the real difference on a plain `list`. Using a semicolon returns a slice, which is a `list`, while a concrete index returns a single element of the list; in this case, an `int`. That is, the **data type** is different.

```
>>> foo = [66,67,68,69]
>>> foo[:1]
[66]
>>> foo[-1:]
[69]
>>> foo[0]
66
>>> foo[-1]
69
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It brings some clearness for me.
But I still don't understand, why do they use path[:1] rather than path[0]?

Comment: @zeLark: If `path` is empty, `path[:1]` will return an empty string, but `path[0]` will raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

slicing works like this:

```
#bring everything from start to end as list
foo[::]

#bring last item as list
foo[-1:]

#careful not to confuse with ->bring last item
foo[-1]
```

slicing basically works like this

```
foo[starting_point:ending_point:step]
#default starting point=0
#default end point is len(foo)
#default step=1
```

Difference between checking `foo[-1]` and `foo[-1:]` besides the fact that the first returns an item(immutable) and the second a list(mutable), is that if `foo[]` is empty, `foo[-1]` will raise an `IndexError` while `foo[-1:]` will return an empty list.

On your link now:
https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/xml/etree/ElementPath.py#l254

We're talking about strings here so result of `path[-1]` and `path[-1:]` will be a string. So the reason why `path[-1:]` is preferred is because if `path=""`, `path[-1]` will raise the `IndexError` while `path[-1:]` will return `""`

Comment: The bits of Python code will look better if you surround them with the backtick character: \`.